# It is possible to load list perl modules depending on conditional statements?

Tags: linux, perl, module

(Correct me if I ask the question in the wrong way).

I am making a standard/generic way to simplify all the scripts/app I am making in linux using perl.

I already found the solution to make standard sub routines and calling them from a file that does most of the standard jobs I want to have (variable declarations/checkers/etc).

Now the last problem I have now is how to call different set of modules(tk, dbi, etc..) which I only need by calling them from a file. Not just that. I made flags which will activate contents from my standard/generic sub routines, now I also want that conditions to be applied when activating only list of modules based on that flag.

Meaning based on the flag that I declared, only those list of modules that needs to be activated will be activated.

How to do that? :)

---

Additional details.

Not modules made using .pm, but Perl modules like:

```pl
use Net::Domain qw(hostname hostfqdn hostdomain);
use Time::Local;
use Time::Piece;
use Switch;
use Exporter;
#use strict;

use File::Basename;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

use Time::Local;                                      
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds();                                     

use Tk;
use Tk::BrowseEntry;
use Tk::Balloon;                                 
use Tk::widgets qw(Checkbutton BrowseEntry);          
use Tk::NoteBook;                                     
use Tk::Pane;   
use Tk::Photo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're free to use 'require' which is only evaluated when the control reaches it in runtime - unlike for 'use's which are getting extracted in BEGIN { }.